# HTML localStorage.clear()

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache

How do i get this to function on page load? 
got it working attached to a button, that eliminates cache when logging out, but if logged in on /sub + entering main the cache is still on main.

used this on button :

```
onClick="LogOut(); localStorage.clear(), window.location.reload()"
```

Eventually is it possible to define in .js (that is locked to all main/sub) what .html file localStorage.clear() should apply to?

Basicly i want to disable all cache on main. and got only access to .html and .js

also. in chrome://cache : `"timestamp=1501542046068&lever1=true&"` is `"lever1"` the cache key? eventually possible just disable that on both pages in .js or html?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `window.onload` to run the function when the page loads. For example:

```
function foo() {
  LogOut();
  localStorage.clear();
  window.location.reload();
}

window.onload = foo()
```

I'm not sure what you mean by the second part of your question, but `localStorage` APIs persist data across browser sessions with the same domain.

Comment: Warning: Code skills : starter.
that has to go in .js right? its a premade website using flask and i only have one custom.js file to enter .js, that code will effect all subdomains to? 
I can however edit all the .html files as much as i want.

Comment: If you do `window.location.reload()` in the `onload` function, you'll get into an infinite loop repeatedly reloading the window.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, after some trying and error this worked.

```
   <script> function foo() {
        localStorage.clear();
                }
 window.onload = foo()</script>
```

this sent it on a repeating refresh loop :

```
<script> function foo() {
  localStorage.clear();
  window.location.reload();
}

window.onload = foo() </script>
```

Thank you.